# How to check if signed in user has timed out in DNN

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I don't know why this is so difficult, but I want to be able to do something (in my DNN module) in the event that a login has timed out due to inactivity.

I have tried checking **Request.IsAuthenticated**, and **HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated**, and even the Dnn UserId but these don't seem to reflect the event where a user has been logged out (both IsAuthenticated properties are always true, and the UserId is what it was for the user).

Any ideas on this?

Thanks

Edit:
According to some information, it should be as simple as checking UserId (if it is -1, it means that the user is no longer signed in) however it always comes back as the user's original ID, which is frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I found this excerpt from DNN Forum site on [Sessions Timeout](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/forumid/197/threadid/445252/scope/posts):

- we don't use sessions, what you describe is authentication cookie timeouts - these are controlled via the forms timeout value in web.config. However I recommend you consider using persistentcookietimeout http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/PersistentCookieTimeout.aspx , though if you don't want to support persistent cooies you can disable the remember me function http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Disabling-support-for-persistent-cookies.aspx

Comment: While this explains some things, it doesn't explain how to handle the event when timeout actually occurs.